# Extract td text from a td colspan tag using bs4

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My goal here is to extract all the contents from the "td" tags below the colspan. I'm just getting started with bs4. So far i can extract all the "trs" from the page however, i would like the information only under the  info_row class named Disks. any help with logic and or code is much appreciated.

This is an excerpt from the HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%" class="info_row">Disks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> sda </td>
        <td> 123456 </td>
        <td> abcdefg </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> sdb </td>
        <td> 123456 </td>
        <td> abcdefg </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Desired output:

```
sda 123456 abcdefg
sbd 123456 abcdefg
```

so far I have the following:

```
src = open("my_page.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
tbody = soup.findAll("tbody")
for tr in tbody:
      tds = tr.findAll('td')
      for td in tds:
        print(td.text)
```

Comment: I modified the code to check if td tag has specific class and text mentioned in your question

Answer (score 3):

The initial for loop finds you the index of the tr tag where td tag has `class="info_row"` and text as `Disks`, using that index you can just find the index of the next tr tag whose text you want to extract and use it as a list index to apply `get_text()` method to extract the text inside the tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = '''<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%" class="info_row">Disks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> sda </td>
        <td> 123456 </td>
        <td> abcdefg </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> sdb </td>
        <td> 123456 </td>
        <td> abcdefg </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
trs = soup.findAll("tr")

for i in range(len(trs)):
    if trs[i].td:
        if 'class' in trs[i].td.attrs and trs[i].td.text == 'Disks':
            if "info_row" in trs[i].td.attrs['class']:
                idx = i
                break

print(' '.join(trs[idx+1].get_text(' ').split()))
print(' '.join(trs[idx+2].get_text(' ').split()))
```

**Output**

```
sda 123456 abcdefg
sdb 123456 abcdefg
```

To get individual elements inside tags, you can use this code because `trs[idx+1].get_text(' ').split()` is actually a list:

```
for item in trs[idx+1].get_text(' ').split():
    print(item)

for item in trs[idx+2].get_text(' ').split():
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
sda
123456
abcdefg
sdb
123456
abcdefg
```

Comment: This works great and very easy to understand! i was getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'" but i was able to work around it by adding a try/except block. Thanks again

Comment: one question, if thats okay. would it be possible to access the td texts individually as well? like if i just wanted 'sda' or '123456" my goal is to store these values in a dictionary.

Comment: @mondragonfx Yes absolutely, `trs[idx+1].get_text(' ').split()` is a list and you can get individual element from this list as per your requirements

Comment: @mondragonfx I modified the code to resolve the issue of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'"

Answer (score 1):

This example select only non-"colspan" rows from the table:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%" class="info_row">Disks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> sda </td>
        <td> 123456 </td>
        <td> abcdefg </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> sdb </td>
        <td> 123456 </td>
        <td> abcdefg </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.select("tr:not(:has([colspan]))"):
    print(*[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")])
```

Prints:

```
sda 123456 abcdefg
sdb 123456 abcdefg
```

---

Or: you can select all rows that are after row that contains cell "Disks":

```
for tr in soup.select('tr:has(> td:contains("Disks")) ~ tr'):
    print(*[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")])
```

---

EDIT: Using `lambda`:

```
for tr in soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "tr" and tag.text.strip() == "Disks").find_next_siblings("tr"):
    print(*[td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer this appears to be work just as expected. would it be possible for td:contains("Disks") to be case/word sensitive? i have other tds in the HTML page that have the word "disks" and this seems to print those as well. otherwise this is spot on. i really appreciate this.

Comment: @mondragonfx You can use `lambda`, I updated my answer.